# Does anybody know of any Simple.Data.Azure sample projects?

Tags: azure, simple.data

I can't seem to find any documentation or sample projects on using simple.data.azure.  Does anybody know of any?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Github repository - https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data.Azure? There are some tests there which should give you some idea. Otherwise I would suggest contacting Mark Rendle (author of this library).

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at the integration tests was wondering if there were more extensive examples. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, do get in touch with Mark. He should be able to help you out.